# SQL - Create a Row for Every Column and Repeat ID

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I am looking to be able to visualize snapshot data and limit the amount of columns I would need to create. My data would look something like this.

```
+----+-------+---------+--------+-------+
| ID |   A   |    B    |   C    |   D   |
+----+-------+---------+--------+-------+
|  1 | Adam  | Anthony | Andy   | Alice |
|  2 | Bob   | Brain   | Bill   | Bing  |
|  3 | Cindy | Cal     | Chris  | Cathy |
|  4 | Dave  | DJ      | Dillon | Dan   |
+----+-------+---------+--------+-------+
```

I want it to look like this

```
+----+--------+---------+
| ID | Column |  Value  |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 | A      | Adam    |
|  1 | B      | Anthony |
|  1 | C      | Andy    |
|  1 | D      | Alice   |
|  2 | A      | Bob     |
|  2 | B      | Brain   |
|  2 | C      | Bill    |
|  2 | D      | Bing    |
|  3 | A      | Cindy   |
|  3 | B      | Cal     |
|  3 | C      | Chris   |
|  3 | D      | Cathy   |
|  4 | A      | Dave    |
|  4 | B      | DJ      |
|  4 | C      | Dillon  |
|  4 | D      | Dan     |
+----+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Also, you have both MySQL and T-SQL in your tags. T-SQL is a Microsoft syntax used in SQL Server. Which are you really using?

Comment: WHY would you change a nice formatted question to image links.  WHY!!!!

Comment: The last edit #3 wasn't helpful at all. It's far better to provide the data as text. Please do a rollback.

Comment: You would probably be better off using the second layout as the real schema of your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION` query to do this:

```
SELECT id, 'A', A as Value FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'B', B FROM table
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, 'C', C FROM table
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, 'D', D FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you using SQL Server, you can try using pivot/unpivot

Since you are trying to rotate the columns(A,B,C,D) to rows, you can use unpivot as follows:

```
 SELECT ID, [Column], [Value]
 FROM 
     (SELECT ID, A, B, C, D
     FROM InitialTable) p
 UNPIVOT
 (Value FOR Column IN 
   (A, B, C, D)
 )AS unpvt;
 GO
```

Answer (score 0):

IF truly SQL Server, I often use a helper Table-Valued-Function to convert rows or queries into an EAV structure (Entity Attribute Value).  No need to specify all the desired fields.

The performance is great, but for larger data-sets **UNPIVOT is far superior**.

Consider the following:

```
Declare @User table (ID int,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50))
Insert into @User values
(1,'John','Smith','john.smith@email.com'),
(2,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@email.com')

Select B.*
 From  @User A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-EAV]((Select A.* for XML RAW)) B
```

Returns

[image]

In the sample above, the function was used in a CROSS APPLY.  It can also be used as a stand-alone call

```
Select * from [dbo].[udf-EAV]((Select * from @User for XML RAW))
```

---

The Function is interested

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-EAV](@XML xml)
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    with cteKey(k) as (Select Top 1 xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') From @XML.nodes('/row') As A(xRow) Cross Apply A.xRow.nodes('./@*') As B(xAtt))    

    Select Entity    = xRow.value('@*[1]','varchar(50)')
          ,Attribute = xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
          ,Value     = xAtt.value('.','varchar(max)') 
    From  @XML.nodes('/row') As A(xRow)
    Cross Apply A.xRow.nodes('./@*') As B(xAtt)
    Where xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') Not In (Select k From cteKey)
)
-- Notes:  First Field in Query will be the Entity
-- Select * From [dbo].[udf-EAV]((Select UTCDate=GetUTCDate(),* From sys.dm_os_sys_info for XML RAW))
```